# Getting the first category of the deepest level for an entry

Tags: categories

I want to get the first category of the deepest level for an entry.

For example if the category structure looks like this

Ocean Life > Fish > Gold Fish

I want "Gold Fish"

Here is what I've come up with so far. Is there a more elegant solution that I'm missing?

```
            {% set primaryCategory = entry.categories.level(3).first %}
            {% if primaryCategory is empty %}
                {% set primaryCategory = entry.categories.level(2).first %}
            {% endif%}
            {% if primaryCategory is empty %}
                {% set primaryCategory = entry.categories.level(1).first %}
            {% endif%}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach for the time being is the code sample in the question. Always open to explore new ideas in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are only assigning one category (and thus by default all of that categories ancestors), then getting the 'last' returned category should work.

```
{% set category = entry.categories.last() %}
```

Otherwise, you will need some logic of some kind. What you have works, or perhaps something where you don't need to know how many levels there are.

```
{% set level = 0 %}
{% for category in entry.categories %}
    {% set level = category.level > level ? category.level : level %}
{% endfor %}
{% set category = entry.categories.level(level).first %}
```

However, this will still not retrieve all the categories if there is more than one category set with same level.

Comment: Interesting! Yes, in my use case there could be two or more categories assigned at level 2 or 3.

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to make an array and sort by level?

Answer (score 1):

You could sort by `level` descending (which will order by deepest-to-shallowest), and then `lft` ascending (which will order by top-to-bottom, for entries at the same level).

```
{% set category = craft.categories()
    .group('myGroup')
    .orderBy('level DESC, lft ASC')
    .one() %}
```

Comment: great, thank you